# When is a default value initialized?

Tags: sql-server, sql

```
create table tab3(a integer,d1 datetime default getdate())
insert into tab3(a) values(1)
insert into tab3 (a) select a from tab3
GO 20
insert into tab3 (a) select a from tab3

select d1,count(*) from tab3(NOLOCK) group by d1
```

The final insert definitely takes a non trivial amount of time(3 seconds on my machine)

However, the value in `d1` is distinct per batch. i.e. the final query returns only 22 rows

```
2014-06-22 20:34:53.787 1
2014-06-22 20:34:56.127 1
2014-06-22 20:34:56.140 2
2014-06-22 20:34:56.153 4
2014-06-22 20:34:56.157 8
2014-06-22 20:34:56.160 16
2014-06-22 20:34:56.163 32
2014-06-22 20:34:56.167 64
2014-06-22 20:34:56.170 128
2014-06-22 20:34:56.177 256
2014-06-22 20:34:56.183 512
2014-06-22 20:34:56.193 1024
2014-06-22 20:34:56.210 2048
2014-06-22 20:34:56.240 4096
2014-06-22 20:34:56.293 8192
2014-06-22 20:34:56.397 16384
2014-06-22 20:34:56.493 32768
2014-06-22 20:34:56.607 65536
2014-06-22 20:34:56.817 131072
2014-06-22 20:34:57.240 262144
2014-06-22 20:34:57.710 524288
2014-06-22 20:35:01.630 1048576
```

Why is GETDATE() initialized per statement instead of per insert?

How can I ensure the default value is initialized per row instead of per statement without the use of a cursor?

EDIT:Probably related,tab3_log has the same schema as tab3

```
CREATE TRIGGER tab3_logger on tab3
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO tab3_log(a) select a from inserted
END
```

Shown all rows from a single insert statement as having the same datetime

Comment: This is a SQL Server idiosyncrasy/design problem. But why do you need this?

Comment: @usr I have some trigger based logging going on in a table, with a default GETDATE() used in the log table. Noticed this behaviour from there and created some test data to investigate. Now, I'm curious about why this happens

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When is a default value initialized?

This depends on whether or not the expression is a "[runtime constant](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/conor_cunningham_msft/archive/2010/04/23/conor-vs-runtime-constant-functions.aspx)".

To get your desired behaviour you can wrap the call in a scalar UDF.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.F()
RETURNS DATETIME
AS
  BEGIN
      RETURN GETDATE()
  END

GO

CREATE TABLE T
  (
     A CHAR(8000) NULL,
     B FLOAT DEFAULT RAND(), 
     C DATETIME DEFAULT GETDATE(),
     D DATETIME DEFAULT dbo.F(),
     E UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT NEWID()
  )

INSERT INTO T
            (A)
SELECT TOP 100000 'A'
FROM   master..spt_values v1,
       master..spt_values v2

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT B) AS B,
       COUNT(DISTINCT C) AS C,
       COUNT(DISTINCT D) AS D,
       COUNT(DISTINCT E) AS E
FROM   T

GO

DROP TABLE T;
DROP FUNCTION F;
```

Returns (example, exact value for `D` will vary)

```
+---+---+-----+--------+
| B | C |  D  |   E    |
+---+---+-----+--------+
| 1 | 1 | 823 | 100000 |
+---+---+-----+--------+
```

The first two are evaluated per statement the second two per row.

Answer (score 3):

SQL is set-based, not row-by-row.  The insert statement logically happens all-at-once so it is correct to assign the same value for all rows inserted by the statement.  You might even get the same getdate value for different statements on a faster machine since getdate only has a precision of a millisecond with an accuracy plus or minus 3-4 milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

Why this happen is something very difficult to tell. I think it is something between optimization and the semantic of the "column default value". Maybe SQL say nothing about this.  But someone could say it's ok for the date to be one for a single transaction.

Not sure how to solve but I would try this:

```
insert into tab3 (a, d1) select a, getdate() from tab3
GO 20
```

Comment: this method exhibits the same behaviour as my original query. the getdate is executed only once per select

Comment: Then you will have to try with some stored procedure with a loop and an insert in it. I think it would be fair to expect the getdate() to be evaluated for every ROW in the select. But Microsoft use to be like this.